# CompletableFuture is blocking thread

Tags: java, concurrency

```
 CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> completableFuture =
        client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    completableFuture
        .thenApplyAsync(HttpResponse::headers)
        .thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println);
    HttpResponse<String> response = completableFuture.join();

sysout("test");
```

there is no print out after join() call, join waits to finish the request.
why?

Comment: Hm... The edited question hav nothing to do with the original one.

Comment: Don't edit your post to completely change what you're asking, invalidating existing answers. If you have a new question, create a new post.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is what join is supposed to do - to wait for the completion.

Comment: how can i get the result without blocking then?

Comment: Dont use join, you will get the result as some point in the future and consumer callback will be applied to the result (methods you are passing to thenApplyAsync)

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Nothing, use callbacks to consume the result ins asynchronous fashion.

Answer (score 1):

while `join` is a blocking call and waits until completableFuture completes. IOW, by calling `join` you turn the async code into a synchronous code.

Comment: how can i get the result without blocking then? i want sysout to print then result comes. in

Comment: `.thenRun(() -> sysout("test));`

Comment: i thikn , code block will not continue executing in async call, because lots of thinks to run

Comment: Don't get confused with `thenRun` and `thenRunAsync`. Most of methods of `CompletableFuture` run asynchronously from the caller point of view. When `CompletableFuture#complete` is called,  then `thenXxxAsync` executed  in a different thread than `complete` is called. That's why all `xxxAsync` methods have a version to explicitly specify which thread pools to use.